# Store intermediate values into array with Ruby inject

Tags: inject

I want to store ruby inject values into array I found one good example (on site http://matthewcarriere.com/2008/06/23/using-select-reject-collect-inject-and-detect/) but its returning Fixnum instead of array.

```
 [1,2,3,4].inject([]) {|acc,n| acc << n+n}
```

this is returning 262144. However I want array as [2, 4, 6, 8].
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it works in my machine.

Have you tried it in a new irb session?

Which version of ruby are you using?

```
$ ruby  --version
ruby 2.3.1p112 (2016-04-26 revision 54768) [x86_64-linux]

$ irb --version
irb 0.9.6(09/06/30)

$ irb
irb(main):001:0> [1,2,3,4].inject([]) {|acc,n| acc << n+n}
=> [2, 4, 6, 8]
irb(main):002:0>
```

Comment: version is same except mine is windows. basically I want array from this but its giving me error as:  irb(main):001:0> (0..30).inject([1,0]) { |(i,j)| i << i+j }
TypeError: nil can't be coerced into Fixnum
        from (irb):1:in `+'
        from (irb):1:in `block in irb_binding'
        from (irb):1:in `each'
        from (irb):1:in `inject'
        from (irb):1
        from C:/Ruby23-x64/bin/irb.cmd:19:in `<main>'

Comment: You are trying to add an integer with an array.

i + j => array + Fixnum.

maybe you are trying to do this.

(0..30).inject([1,0]) { |i,j| i << j +j }

Comment: oh you are correct, thanks I got why I am getting error. but I want to add previous number of array (i.e. i want to get fibonacci series till 30th position). I will really appreciate If you can guide.

Comment: (0..30).inject([0,1]) { |i| i << i[-1] + i[-2] }